# Find angles in 4-sided polygon

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Does anyone have an idea of how to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the following scenario?

- $a$, $b$, $c$ and $h$ are known.
- $h$ is orthogonal to $c$.
  [image]
  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any particular reason why you think this has a good looking solution? Also, can you give more context as to where this problem arised?

Comment: @HackR, I am not sure if there is any good looking solution. I tried to find one for a whole day and thought that maybe someone has already seen something like this or has an idea in which I direction I could work on. I would like to give you more context, but this would need a lot more space than a comment. In short: at the points at alpha and beta, cables are attached (with a fixed distance), which are then attached to a box at h (h is always orthogonal to c, but can vary in height and position).

Comment: translate the triangle on the right downward for a distance $h$, you will find $\alpha = \beta' + \tan^{-1}\frac{h}{c}$ where $\beta'$ is the angle $B$ of a triangle $ABC$ with sides $a, b$ and $c' = \sqrt{c^2+h^2}$.

Comment: @achillehui Amazing. This is the solution. Thank you very much! If you want to post your comment as an answer, I can check it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-Noting $x,y,z$ as in the figure below you do have
$$\alpha=\arcsin \left(\dfrac{x+h}{a}\right)\\\beta=\arcsin \left(\dfrac{x}{b}\right)$$ The system giving $x,y,z$ is
$$y+z=c\\x^2+z^2=b^2\\(x+h)^2+y^2=a^2$$
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is also a solution to this problem, but for me it looks like @achille hui's answer (see the comments above) is easier to calculate.